I get Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource lambda
I am building a serveless framework template containing a custom resource backed with lambda that i want to provide its AWS ARN as ServiceToken but I get Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource lambda
service: app

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: us-east-2
  stackName: app
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - logs:*
          - cloudwatch:GenerateQuery
        Resource: "*"

functions:
  Initializer:
    name: Initializer
    handler: src/Initializer.handler
    runtime: nodejs18.x


resources:
  Resources:
    CustomResource:
      Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
      Properties:
        ServiceToken:
          "Fn::GetAtt": [ Initializer, Arn ]


Have you already tried ServiceToken: !GetAtt Initializer.Arn instead?
